# How do I perform two opposite functions with "onclick" on a single element

Tags: javascript, html

I have an html text-box. I want a JavaScript that expands the text box on first click and returns it to it's original size on second click. Ps: I'm new to JS.

Comment: You will get more help if you share the relevant code. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using the `toggle()` function on the `HTMLElement.classList` as follows.

```js
document.querySelector('div').addEventListener('click', ({ target }) => {
  target.classList.toggle('blue');
});
```

```css
div {
  color: red;
}

.blue {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div>My Text</div>
```

Comment: You can specify different height and width properties for your divs to toggle a change in size.

Comment: @moritzsalla absolutely, was just trying to give a very simple demonstration of `toggle`

Comment: My comment was meant for the author :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a variable `count = 0`. On Each click, you can do `count++`.

So the expand logic would be like :

```js
if (count % 2 === 1) {  
  // for odd number of clicks
  // will expand my text box
} else {
  // for even number of clicks
  // will shrink
}
```

Comment: Salman Santino, I like this idea. Too bad I'm unable to implement it at this stage.